# How to use SET method on the LISTVIEW.SELECTION in WINJS

Tags: windows-8, winjs, windows-8.1

Anybody ever used the `listView.selection.set(items)` method in WINJS?

I can make it work if I pass the numeric index of an item, but I can't manage to have it work passing a key.

This is the documentation on how it should work but there is no example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh872207.aspx

Comment: nobody ever used this method?

Comment: Wow I cannot believe this is a difficult question

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is find the index of the item you want, and then use listView.selection.set(item);

```
 for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    var item = list.getAt(i);
    if (item.key == yourKey){
       listView.selection.set(i);
       i = list.length;
    }
 }
```

Comment: As I said in my question I know how to use the set() method passing an id, what I need is to find out the "key" of the item and use the method with a key. It is specified in the second part of the documentation in the link I provide, but there is no example and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer, but I'm answering because I was looking for a way to do this almost 1 year later.

In order to select by key, the object you pass to `set` must contain keys, ie.

```
var newSelection = [{key: 3}, {key: 5}];
listView.selection.set(newSelection);
```

If you want to preserve the selection after changing the data, there doesn't seem to be a correct way to access the current selection, so I used `_value`.

```
var listView = document.getElementById("ListView").winControl;
var oldSelection = listView.selection._value;
//Sort the list, or do something that changes the list.
listView.selection.set(oldSelection);
```